# Wrong output for factorial decomposition

Tags: c

I have made a delphi program for factorial decomposition and it looks like this:

[image]

40 is the number and when you click "Scomponi" you have the correct output (2^3 * 5 = 40). I've made a C program that should do the same thing but I have this output:

[image]

As you can see, the numbers on the right are correct (2^3 * 5) but the numbers on the left aren't. This is the code I wrote:

```
int main()
{
 long a,b=2;  
 printf("------------------------------------------------ \n \n"); 
 printf("Inserisci il numero di cui vuoi la scomposizione \n"); //input number (it's the 40 of the example)
 scanf("%d", &a);
 printf("\n------------------------------------------------ \n\n");
 printf("Scomposizione: \n \n"); //Decomposition
  while(a>1)
  {
   if(a%b == 0)      
    {
     printf("%d \t \t | %d \n",a,b);
     a=a/b;   
    }
   else
    {
     b++;    
    } 
    printf("%d", a);
  }
   printf("\n------------------------------------------------ \n\n");
 getch();
 return 0;    
}
```

What could I do for fix this problem?

Comment: I would suppose this `printf("%d", a);` is superfluous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   else
    {
     b++;    
    } 
    printf("%d", a);
  }
```

The last `printf` should not be here. Remove it.

As a side note:

`a` and `b` are of type `long`.

So instead of:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

you have to use:

```
scanf("%ld", &a);
```

Same for `printf`, use `%ld` conversion specification instead of `%d`.